# Adding DatagridviewComboboxCell to new row

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I am adding a row on the button click event and adding combobox in a row cell but I am not able to bind the values in that cell combobox. Can any one suggest me what I am doing wrong??

```
DataGridViewRow dgr = new DataGridViewRow();            

DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
cbCol.Items.Add("Test");
cbCol.Items.Add("Test");
cbCol.Items.Add("Test");
cbCol.Items.Add("Test");       

dgr.Cells.Add(cbCol);

dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgr);
```

The above code is written in a button click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are attempting to do should not be necessary.

You grid should have a column of type `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` which has a DataSource set that provides the values available for all cells in that column.

When you add a new row to the grid you will automatically get a cell in the combobox column with the values you need. If you want to have different values in each row then you can use the `EditingControlShowing` event of the grid to change the combobox data source.